# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null(…) in a JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

This method is part of a module; And despite the error...

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null(…)`

works to a small degree, however it appears to have blocked an additional method on the module.

This is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/718BkQns/1xomL42r/7/) which contains the whole module.

```js
searchURL: function() {
  function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
  }
  var link, url, parser, newPathName = '',
    newstr = '',
    doc = document,
    avon_rep_container = doc.getElementById('avon_rep_container'),
    avon_rep_container_id,
    avon_rep_container_links,
    avon_rep_container_images,
    documentTableWrapper,
    docBodyFirstChild,
    full_width_container_1 = doc.getElementsByClassName('full-width-container')[1],
    full_width_img_class_el = doc.getElementsByClassName('full-width-img')[0];
  if (!avon_rep_container) {
    avon_rep_container = doc.createElement('div');
    avon_rep_container.setAttribute('id', 'avon_rep_container');
    avon_rep_container.className = 'container-avon-representative-news';
    avon_rep_container_links = avon_rep_container.getElementsByTagName('a');
    avon_rep_container_id = doc.getElementById('avon_rep_container');
    docBodyFirstChild = doc.body.firstChild;
    documentTableWrapper = doc.getElementsByClassName('marginfix')[0];
    avon_rep_container.appendChild(documentTableWrapper);
    doc.body.appendChild(avon_rep_container);
    full_width_container_1.removeChild(full_width_container_1.getElementsByTagName('table')[0]);
    full_width_img_class_el.removeAttribute('style');
  } else {
    avon_rep_container_links = doc.getElementById('avon_rep_container').getElementsByTagName('a');
  }
  avon_rep_container_images = avon_rep_container.getElementsByTagName('img');
  for (var i = 0; i < avon_rep_container_images.length; i++) {
    var images = avon_rep_container_images[i];
    images.src = '/dam/avon-us/landing-pages/rep-news/' + images.src.split('/').pop();
    if (avon_rep_container_images[i].width == "538") {
      avon_rep_container_images[i].style.width = "538px";
    }
    if (avon_rep_container_images[i].width == "258") {
      avon_rep_container_images[i].style.width = "258px";
    }
    avon_rep_container_images[i].style.width = 'inherit';
    avon_rep_container_images[i].style.margin = 'auto';
  }
  //for (var i = 0, len = arguments.length; i < len; i++) { // Using a for loop to allow unlimited arguments to be passed in
  //instead collect all necessary urls
  url = getURL(arguments); //[i]); // We are calling the publicApi.getURL() method and passing the looped argument from above
  for (var j = 0, jlen = avon_rep_container_links.length; j < jlen; j++) { // This loop goes over the whole documents links...
    link = avon_rep_container_links[j];
    var domain = link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//)[1];
    if ((url.indexOf(domain) !== -1) && (!link.href.match(/\.(pdf)/gi))) { // //...and we are checking each argument passed in to see if it matches the object value stored in the getURL function e.g. like a switch statement..
      parser = document.createElement('a'); //...if so we are essentially adding a blank tag to all the documents in the document
      parser.href = link.href;
      link.setAttribute('target', '_self');
      newPathName = parser.pathname;
      console.log(domain);
      if (newPathName.search(/Executive|District|Division|National/) != -1) { // Added check for these strings for SMO page
        newPathName = newPathName.split('/').pop();
        newstr = newPathName;
      } else {
        newstr = newPathName;
      }
      link.href = newstr;
    } else {
      link.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
    }
  }
  //}
}
```

Can one explain what the error means in context to my Module, can't seem to understand it.

Thanks any help will be appreciated!

**Update**

This is where the error is occurring:

```
var domain=link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//)[1];
```

Comment: It would help if you told us which line was throwing the error.

Comment: Pretty obvious by the error - you're trying to select something at the index of `1` - but there is nothing there. `link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//)` is returning `null`

Comment: Based on your update: look at what the value of `link.href` is. Apparently, it does not match your regex.

Comment: You're not matching enough results to read index[1].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns either `null` (no match) or an array with the matches.

```
var domain = link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//)[1];
//                     ^^^^^
```

Workaround with check

```
var domain = link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//);

if (domain) {
    // do something with domain[1]
}
```

Comment: Hey Nina, Thanks a lot! I am going to have to read up on the `match` now!

Answer (score 2):

Per [string.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match):

> #### Return value
>
> An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results; null if there were no matches.

The regular expression should match the string, as well as the protocol and domain like you have it (i.e. the grouping surrounded by parentheses `(https?:\/\/.+?)`). You can ensure that the return value is not null (so it should be an array) and that is has more that one element before attempting to access index 1 (since the 1st index should be 0) like this:

```
var matches = link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//);
if (matches !== null && matches.length > 1) {
```

So take a look at this example:

```js
function match(link) {
    var matches=link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//);
    if (matches !== null && matches.length > 1) {
        var protocolAndDomain = matches[1];
          console.log('protocol and domain: ',protocolAndDomain );
    }
    else {
          console.log('no matching protocol and domain');
    }
}
var link = { href: 'stackoverflow.com'};
match(link); //should find no matches

var link2 = { href: 'https://domain.com/'};
match(link2); //should match https://domain.com
```

I use the term *protocol and domain* because the expression is looking for the protocol (i.e. *https://*) before the domain.  For more information about the parts of the URL, [refer to this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Basics_anatomy_of_a_URL).

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Sam, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

You can use an if statement to check if the match is null like the other answers have mentioned.

Or you can use the logical or operator to get it onto one line and make it cleaner e.g.

`var domain = (link.href.match(/(https?:\/\/.+?)\//) || [])[1];`

You get a Type error because when the match is false the function returns `null` and you cannot access index 1 of `null` as it is not an array.

`null[1]` causes a type error

By using the logical OR operator `||` the domain variable is set to second condition when the first condition is falsey.

So when the match is false the result defaults to an empty array `[]` and you can access any index of an empty array without getting an error and it results in `undefined`

This will make `domain = undefined` when the match is false.

I really wish type errors weren't a problem in JS especially with objects. I seem to have add a lot of if statement and extra code every other line just to deal with type errors.