# ionic 2 - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: javascript, ionic2

I notice my `ionic 2` have this error if I use `Chrome` running on `iphone5`, `iphone6`,`ipad` or `iPad pro`:

> kernel.js:281 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

which apparently is coursed by this line:

```
...
ver: (navigator.appVersion.match('Chrome/([0-9\.]+)') || 

navigator.userAgent.match('Firefox/([0-9\.]+)'))[1],///<---[1] is the issue
...
```

I googled and read a bit about this and it seems like it is because of the `[1]`. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40554652/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-1-of-null-in-a-javascript-function) suggest to remove `[1]`. But I am not sure where the `kernel.js` is.

It is not an issue now because I only deploy to `Android`(Strangely, even in simulation there is no issue. only on all the `ios` be it simulation or device). But I think is better to resolve it so that my client will not bark at me when they decided to deploy to `ios`.

How should I resolve this?

2. Where can I find the `kernel.js`? I look into `node_modules` and it is too big to search. I want to try delete it and see if it give me issue.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript `String.match()` function will return null if there are no matches, so in your case if the useragent is not FireFox. The same error should also occur on Browsers other than Chrome or FireFox on Android. You will need to check for that.

**EDIT**:
Chrome on iOS is not marked as 'Chrome' in the navigator but instead as 'CriOS'. See: https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/user-agent